# Unable to make recursive call in Javascript

Tags: javascript

When I try to run this program, I get an error in Firefox saying that:

> moveDate is undefined on line 41

(referring to the line `window.setTimeout("moveDate()",100);`.

Any ideas why? I thought recursive functions were able to define themselves and then call upon themselves.

```
function monthScroller(){
    document.getElementById("month").style.visibility = "visible";
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var dest_x = window.innerWidth/2;
    var dest_y = window.innerHeight/2;  
    var interval = 1;

    function moveDate() {
        if(x<dest_x){ x = x + interval;} 
        if(y<dest_y){ y = y + interval;}

        document.getElementById("month").style.top  = y+"px";
        document.getElementById("month").style.left = x+"px";

        if ((x+interval < dest_x) && (y+interval < dest_y)) {
                window.setTimeout("moveDate()",100);
        }
        else{
            name();
        }
    }
    moveDate();
}
```

Comment: `eval()` is `evil`. Don't use those, including that one in `setTimeout("")`.

Comment: Derek, you beat me to the eval() is evil line. Anyway, this blog post explains more about why you don't want to use strings to evaluate code dynamically (which is what setTimeout does when you use a string).

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx

Comment: It's not really recursive, moveDate() will complete its call about 100ms before it is run again from your setTimeout call if you follow the advice of the answerers.

Comment: @Derek—give it a rest. The "eval is evil" mantra started over a decade ago and was fundamentally not about evaluating strings in `setTimeout` and `setInterval` (and Function), they were side issues. The only problem with its use here relates to efficiency (ignoring the scope issue), none of the other "evilness" of eval is relevant here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they are. Yet, `window.setTimeout("moveDate()",100);` will eval that *code string* in the global scope - no `moveDate` to be found there. Instead, pass the function reference to [`setTimout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout):

```
 window.setTimeout(moveDate, 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

"moveDate" is scoped inside of the monthScroller method. Anything outside of the brackets of the monthScroller function can't see the "moveDate" function. So... when the setTimeout runs, the scope "window" and window doesn't have a function named "moveDate" in scope. What you need to do is change the call to the following:

```
setTimeout(moveDate,100);
```

That should work for you. That way you are passing the moveDate function/object into the setTimeout.