# can not define a function inside jquery? ... undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do something that I thought was simple but I need some help.

inside a jquery function I want to set a timer and clear it from another function....

```
(function($){

var mnuTimer;
var mnuDown;

$('.nav-menu .parent').hover(function(){
    clearTimeout(mnuTimer);//clear function
    $(this).children('.children').slideDown();
    $(this).css('background-color','#fff0c8');
},
function(){
    function mnuDown(){//set function for timer experation
      $(this).children('.children').slideUp('fast');
      $(this).css('background-color','transparent');
      }
    mnuTimer = setTimeout("mnuDown()",1000)//timer
});

})(jQuery);
```

So the only part I can't get working is the timer. the "mnuDown" function comes up undefined. I have tried a lot of different ways to make it work and nothing seem to be correct except declaring the function outside of the jquery "(function($){". This will not work because the whole reason I'm using jquery is to apply the slideUp animation which is not available outside jquery. AHHH help, Thanks

Comment: That's because the string `"mnuDown()"` is evaluated in global scope. `mnuDown` is not global though.

Comment: In general, it is preferred that you use function references in `setTimeout`, not code strings.  Use `setTimeout(mnuDown,1000)`, **not** `setTimeout("mnuDown()",1000)`.  This is also solve your current problem.

Comment: _"can not define a function inside jquery?"_ - Felix's link will give you the answer, but note that this has nothing to do with whether you're using jQuery, it is just normal, correct behaviour in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just repeating [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10809791/1048572):

Yes, not the declaration of the function is the problem but the [variable] referencing it: You have none. Instead, `setTimeout("mnuDown()",1000)` will eval that *code string* in the global scope - no `mnuDown` to be found there. You need to pass the function reference to [`setTimout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout):

```
mnuTimer = setTimeout(mnuDown,1000); //timer
```

Comment: Thanks for the help you guys were correct. Also I had an error in my mnuDown function. I was using $(this) which was null.